# Is it possible to disable the ALT+letter combination shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

When a window is in focus, hitting ALT will somehow "steal focus" and select the menu with the underline letter.

Is it possible to entirely disable this behavior?

[image]

Edit: found the solution, so marked as duplicate:

[Windows 10: How to disable menu bar toggle by pressing ALT?](https://superuser.com/questions/1086805/windows-10-how-to-disable-menu-bar-toggle-by-pressing-alt)

Also relevant:

[Disable the activation of the menu bar when Alt is pressed in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/309005/disable-the-activation-of-the-menu-bar-when-alt-is-pressed-in-windows-7)

Comment: why do you press Alt alone?

Comment: I think the critical bit is why.  There may be other solutions to your problem.

Comment: @phuclv I use a autohotkey script to do accents, and sometimes I hit ALT alone by mistake, so it's a bit annoying.

Comment: @jokoon accents are done by AltGr which is the right Alt, so left Alt for the menu shouldn't affect that

Comment: Not on an US keyboard, I'm not using an international layout. Also the right ALT key is not ergonomic.

Comment: Does any of these alternatives work:  https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97413-turn-off-underline-access-key-shortcuts-menus-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I tried, it doesn't, did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, no the expected answer, and I don't know if it's possible (it may, why not?) but what you are asking is not the standard expected behaviour. It has been part of the [interface guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/) since DOS with [CUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) that expects left <kbd>Alt</kbd> to access menu item and <kbd>F1</kbd> to call help, etc.